# installing an HP LaserJet 1020 printer on win7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have a 2GB Acer laptop on which I'm trying to install the printer, here's what I've tried to do so far:

1. As expected I went to [HP Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-LaserJet-1000-Printer-series/439423/model/439428) and downloaded the 2.6 driver file, when I launched it it got stuck on `preinstalling drive files` and then an exception pops up, I'd have posted a screenshot but the whole system is in Arabic, but the exception has the number c000000d and it has something to do with `ProductInstall.exe` and BEX, googling has returned a suggestion that my security software is blocking the installation, I deactivated protection and tried again, same problem
2. Having failed in the previous step I downloaded the [18MB UPD 5](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/solutions/business-solutions/printingsolutions/UPD.html?jumpid=af_s73wr2vct6) universal driver. Launching it, I chose a USB install, waited for the files to be copied and then tried to connect the printer, the thing is that first I got: the device couldn't be installed and I had to disconnect the cable multiple times, but when I opened device manager the printer is showing under `other devices` with its name and everything
3. Now I got to MS word to print a test page and when I hit print, nothing happened even though the printer is showing `ready` as a status.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: See if this utility from HP can help solve it.....https://support.hp.com/us-en/topic/printscandoctor

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to use the Windows 7 Drivers.

Go to Devices and Printers, remove the printer, then click once on any other device to open the Printer Server Management tab. Go to drivers and remove the Driver for this printer.

Now restart the computer and see if you can add the printer in Windows (rather than using HP driver)

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion,I'll try that ASAP